# Undeclared Identifier for UI fields in custom function

Tags: objective-c, undeclared-identifier

I created a custom function shown below with code I copied from a button click event in my .m file.  The code worked fine until I copied it into my displayDev function.  The last three lines in this code give me a "Use of undeclared identifier" error.  Can someone help me figure out why fullVerseLabel.text, VerseField.text, and InterpretationField.text are all displaying as undeclared identifiers?  Also below is my .h code where I declared these UI fields.

Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks so much!

```
void displayDev (NSInteger dayNum)
{   NSString *plistFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Property List" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistFile];

    NSString *bookString = [[dict objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Day %d", dayNum]] objectForKey:@"Book"];
    NSString *chapterString = [[dict objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Day %d", dayNum]] objectForKey:@"Chapter#"];
    NSString *verseString = [[dict objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Day %d", dayNum]] objectForKey:@"Verse#"];

    NSString *fullVerseString = [bookString stringByAppendingString:@" "];
    fullVerseString = [fullVerseString stringByAppendingString:chapterString];
    fullVerseString = [fullVerseString stringByAppendingString:@":"];
    fullVerseString = [fullVerseString stringByAppendingString:verseString];
    fullVerseLabel.text = fullVerseString;
    VerseField.text = [dict objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Day %d", dayNum]objectForKey:@"Verse"];
    InterpretationField.text = [dict objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Day %d", dayNum] objectForKey:@"Interpretation"];

    currentlyViewing = dayNum;
}
```

I have the variables declared in my .h file and linked to my storyboard.

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController
{   IBOutlet UILabel *fullVerseLabel;
    IBOutlet UITextView *VerseField;
    IBOutlet UITextView *InterpretationField;
    IBOutlet UITextField *TextField;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You started this method with:

```
void displayDev (NSInteger dayNum)
```

With that syntax, you're actually declaring this as a C function, not Objective-C.  You're unable to access your outlets or other instance variables in a C function.  You can change it to an Objective-C instance method by changing the first line to:

```
- (void)displayDev:(NSInteger)dayNum
```